# Python django auth test

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to write tests for my python django application. For tests, I need to get an API token, I tried it through APIClient with this code:

```
   client = APIClient()
   responce = json.loads(client.post('/api-token-auth/',data={"username":"root", "password":"root"}).content)
```

But in return I get

```
{'non_field_errors': ['Unable to login with provided credentials.']}
```

Through the "requests" library and Postman everything works with the same data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably haven't populated your test database yet. Django defaults to creating a new database for model tests. (E.g: Authorization tests needs a user record to properly authorize it)

Here is a relevant line from the documentation why it does that:

[Tests that require a database (namely, model tests) will not use your “real” (production) database. Separate, blank databases are created for the tests.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database)

Running the setup function should help you kickstart what you want to do on your testcase:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class AuthTestCase(APITestCase):
   def setUp(self):
      get_user_model().objects.create(username="root", "password": make_password("root"))
      return super().setUp()

   def test_login_not_authorized_succeeds(self):
       ....
```

Refer to this documentation for additional information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/overview/#writing-tests